# How do I monetize my Kivy app with an adsense alternative like Facebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, ads, kivymd

I don't want to fuss about getting a website at the moment, I just want to focus on completing my app and getting the ad feature to run properly while I prepare to beta-test my kivy app.

However, google seems like a pain. I have to wait for them to approve my adsense account. That is a huge waste of time waiting just to be able to code that feature into my app.

Question 1: What other services can I use instead of AdSense that will integrate with kivy?
I tried signing up for AdBuddiz which I got from Kivy's Github but AdBuddiz sign up process is not working

```
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/AdBuddiz-Android-advertisements-integration-for-Kivy-apps
```

Question 2: If you need a website for an adense account, how do developers run ads in their apps without a website for that app?

Question 3: Are there better options for running ads in my kivy app?

Question 4: Is it possible to monetize my kivy app with Facebook Audience Network?

Comment: about the 2nd. so after 5 seconds of searching on google I found this: https://admob.google.com/home/ which seems to be adsense but for apps so maybe that is what You need, especially if adsense requires a web page, maybe it means it is not meant for apps? also what do You mean whether there are better options for running ads in Your app? also if talking about monetization (4th question), theoretically anything can be monetized so You could monetize the app by putting in self made ads that say for example redirect people to Your affiliate links or sth like that

Comment: admob is part of google. You need an adsense account to get an admob account.

Better options as in alternatives to google adsense

Comment: this seems to be an alternative: https://yandex.com/inapp?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=app122020&utm_content=en_app (again just googled which basically means I have no idea about it but it seems promising) (I guess someone with experience in this will help better, just tried my best)

Comment: At least you already gain a bit of knowledge if you ever need to do this in the future. I am looking for some experienced feedback. I don't want to run into problems in the future. I know google has a tendency to stop AdSense payout to websites with unusually high traffic. I don't know if they do the same with apps since they can measure the downloads

Comment: check that bro hope it make you happy https://github.com/MichaelStott/KivMob

Comment: Bahae El Hmimdi, that is for google's admob. I am not looking for google.